# in_array for a combo value ('test','value')

Tags: php, arrays

I'm trying to use in_array or something like it for associative or more complex arrays.

This is the normal in_array

```
in_array('test', array('test', 'exists')); //true
in_array('test', array('not', 'exists')); // false
```

What I'm trying to search is a **pair**, like the combination 'test' and 'value'. I can set up the combo to be searched to `array('test','value')` or `'test'=>'value'` as needed. But how can I do this search if the array to be searched is

```
array('test'=>'value', 'exists'=>'here');
or
array( array('test','value'), array('exists'=>'here') );
```

Comment: Do you mean that you need to search recursively (at any depth)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
if (
    array_key_exists('test', $array) && $array['test'] == 'value' // Has test => value
    ||
    in_array(array('test', 'value'), $array) // Has [test, value]
) {
    // Found
}
```

Comment: `(a && b) || c` is understandable to avoid confusion, but `(c)` is totally unnecessary.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to see if there is a key "test" with a value of "value" then try this:

```
<?php
$arr = array('key' => 'value', 'key2' => 'value');
if(array_key_exists('key',$arr) && $arr['key'] == 'value'))
     echo "It is there!";
else
     echo "It isn't there!";
?>
```

Comment: It would be interesting to see which method was faster isset($arr['key']) or array_key_exists('key',$arr); -- I've never found array_key_exists useful..

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly, you're looking for a function called [array_search()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-search.php)

It accepts a mixed value, so you can even search for objects - I haven't tried it exactly, but it should work for your use case:

```
if (array_search(array('test','value'), array(array('test','value'),array('nottest','notvalue'))) !== false) {
    // item found...
}
```

ok..

### However I think you'll find this method the most useful:

If you just need to find out if a certain key/value pair is located in an array, the easiest way to do it is like this:

```
<?php
if (isset($arr['key']) && $arr['key'] == 'value') { 
    // we have a match...
}
?>
```

if you need to find something in a more complex pattern, there's no avoid creating a bigger loop.

Answer (score 0):

Separate `Keys` from `Values` and use `in_array()`

```
$myArray = array('test'=>'value', 'exists'=>'here');
array_keys($myArray)
array_values($myArray)
```